# How can i update a Schema model field when another Schema model field changes in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to make the PostSchema username get updated whenever UserSchema username changes

```
//This is the user Schema

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: false,
    },
    profilePic: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

```
//This is the PostSchema

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: false,
    },
    profileDp: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

So how do I create a relationship in the PostSchema such that whenever the UserSchema username changes, the PostSchema username should also change?

So far, i've seen $set, ref, or even populate() being recommended, but I'm still unsure of how to do this.

I also tried this, still didn't work

```
UserSchema.pre(["updateOne", "findOneAndUpdate", "findByIdAndUpdate", "updateMany" ], async function (next) {
    if(this.get("username")){
         let userDoc = await mongoose.model("user").findOne(this._conditions);
         await mongoose.model("post").updateOne({ username: userDoc.username },{
         username: this.get("username")
         });
    }
    next();
  })
```